# async POST request using Promises

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, form-data

I'm building a simple uploader, and I've build many before however none using promises, and I've ran into a problem. When I call my promise I need to bind my "uploaded files" to say a form data object aka `data.append('xls', e.dataTransfer.files[0])` in the code below, however I don't have access to the `e` event anymore so I can't access it and bind it to the form `data` object.

The error - `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: e is not defined`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        //HELPER FUNCTION
        events = (o,type,handle)=>o.addEventListener(type,handle);
        listen = {
            drag: ['dragenter','dragover','drop','dragleave'],
            async: ['readystatechange','loadstart','progress','abort','error','load','timeout','loadend']
        };

        //PROMISES
        executor = {
            upload: (resolve,reject) =>{
                var data = new FormData();
                var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
                for(prop of listen.async){ events(client, prop, callback.upload[prop]);}

                //THIS IS WHERE MY PROBLEM LIES         
                data.append('xls', e.dataTransfer.files[0]);  
                client.addEventListener("load", callback.upload);
                client.open("POST", "/core/upload.php");
                client.send(data);
            }
        };

        //PROMISE CALLBACKS
        resolve = (value)=> console.log(value);
        reject = (reason)=> console.log(reason);    

        //EVENT HANDLES
        handles = {
            upload: {
                dragenter: (e)=> e.target.classList.remove('emboss'),
                dragover: (e)=> e.preventDefault(),
                drop: (e)=> {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var p = new Promise(executor.upload);
                    console.log(p);
                },
                dragleave: (e)=> e.target.classList.add('emboss')   
            }
        };

        //ASYNC CALLBACKS
        callback = {
            upload: {
                readystatechange: (e)=> console.log(e.target.readyState),
                loadstart: (e)=> console.log('loadstart'),
                progress: (e)=> console.log('progress'),
                abort: (e)=> console.log('abort'),
                error: (e)=> console.log('error'),
                load: (e)=> console.log('load'),
                timeout: (e)=> console.log('timeout'),
                loadend: (e)=> console.log('loadend')
            }   
        };

        //INITIALIZATION
        init=()=>{
            var dropbox = document.getElementById('dropbox');
            for(prop of listen.drag){ events(dropbox, prop, handles.upload[prop]);}
        };  

        events(document,'DOMContentLoaded', init);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='dropbox' class='fa fa-file-excel-o fa-4x emboss'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a syntax error.

Comment: Does adding `files` as a property of  `executor`, refer to as `this.files` instead of `e.dataTransfer.files` and set it `e.dataTransfer.files` before calling the executor work?

Comment: @Traktor53 that sounds like it will work ill try it.

Comment: @Traktor53 niceeee! yea it worked using `executor.upload.files` not `this.files` because the fat arrow syntax doesn't lexically bind the `this` value https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions,  but if I call it like `data.append('xls', executor.upload.files)` it works fine, thanks!

Comment: If you can post the answer so I can mark it right.

Comment: Hope I've captured the essence. I will look into "Arrow functions capture the this value of the enclosing context" in more detail ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic issue is to pass a parameter obtained from an event object, to the executor function of a Promise, noting the executor is called **synchronously** by the Promise constructor.

One method might be to create an executor factory function that held the parameter in a closure, but this might be overkill when storing the file parameter value where the executor can access it should work equally well.
Setting a property of, say, the upload function object, something like:

```
executor = {
    upload: (resolve,reject) =>{
            var data = new FormData();
            var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
            for(prop of listen.async){ events(client, prop, callback.upload[prop]);}

            data.append('xls', executor.upload.files);
            ....  // etc
```

and set the parameter before creating the promise,

```
. . .
executor.upload.files = e.dataTransfer.files[0]`;
var p = new Promise(executor.upload);
. . .
```